# How to reply to someone's tweet using node.js twit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm trying to make a bot that responds to my friend's tweets with an image every time they tweet. Everything works fine, but I can't get it to respond to the original tweet, only replies. Is there any way to do this?

```js
function tweetEvent(tweetMsg) {
    
    var replyto = tweetMsg.in_reply_to_screen_name;
    var from = tweetMsg.user.screen_name;
    var id = tweetMsg.id_str;

    if(from === "---"){
        
        var b64content = fs.readFileSync('media/img.png', {
            encoding: 'base64'
        })

        T.post('media/upload', {
            media_data: b64content
        }, uploaded);

        function uploaded(err, data, response) {

            var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string;
            var params = {
                status,
                in_reply_to_status_id: id,
                media_ids: [mediaIdStr]
                }
            //! Post tweet
            T.post('statuses/update', params, tweeted);
            };

        function tweeted(err, reply) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log();
                console.log("Error.");
            } else {
                console.log("tweeted");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I want it to reply to the original tweet, the only way it's worked is by using:

```
if(replyto === "---"){ 

}
```

But that doesn't do what I want it to do.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on your question because I'm able to reply to original tweets with an image. Are you asking how to determine if `tweetMsg` is an original post or a reply and then only reply to it if it is an original post?

Comment: Pretty much, I just can't get it to reply to the original post, only a reply.

Comment: So if tweetMsg is a reply you want it to do nothing? And when tweetMsg is an original post you want it to reply?

Comment: Yep exactly that. I don't want it replying to everything my friend tweets, only their original posts.

Comment: I posted my answer, did it help you? Or was in not the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with `if (tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name === null) tweetEvent(tweet);`

```js
const tweets = [
  {
    created_at: "Wed Feb 10 03:50:17 +0000 2021",
    id: 1359348938248183800,
    id_str: "1359348938248183809",
    text: "reply test 1290hHhbjikl",
    truncated: false,
    entities: [Object],
    metadata: [Object],
    source:
      '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
    in_reply_to_status_id: 1359339654080790500,
    in_reply_to_status_id_str: "1359339654080790530",
    in_reply_to_user_id: 1167232572067369000,
    in_reply_to_user_id_str: "1167232572067368960",
    in_reply_to_screen_name: "OpenDreamPhone",
    user: [Object],
    geo: null,
    coordinates: null,
    place: null,
    contributors: null,
    is_quote_status: false,
    retweet_count: 0,
    favorite_count: 0,
    favorited: false,
    retweeted: false,
    lang: "in",
  },
  {
    created_at: "Wed Feb 10 03:13:23 +0000 2021",
    id: 1359339654080790500,
    id_str: "1359339654080790530",
    text: "this is a test. 1290hHhbjikl",
    truncated: false,
    entities: [Object],
    metadata: [Object],
    source:
      '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
    in_reply_to_status_id: null,
    in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
    in_reply_to_user_id: null,
    in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
    in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
    user: [Object],
    geo: null,
    coordinates: null,
    place: null,
    contributors: null,
    is_quote_status: false,
    retweet_count: 0,
    favorite_count: 0,
    favorited: false,
    retweeted: false,
    lang: "en",
  },
];
const tweetEvent = (tweet) => {
  var b64content = fs.readFileSync("twitt/img.png", {
    encoding: "base64",
  });

  T.post(
    "media/upload",
    {
      media_data: b64content,
    },
    uploaded
  );

  function uploaded(err, data, response) {
    var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string;
    var params = {
      status: "hi",
      in_reply_to_status_id: tweet.id_str,
      media_ids: [mediaIdStr],
    };
    //! Post tweet
    T.post("statuses/update", params, tweeted);
  }

  function tweeted(err, reply) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log();
      console.log("Error.");
    } else {
      console.log(reply);
      console.log("tweeted");
    }
  }
};

tweets.forEach((tweet) => {
  if (tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name === null) tweetEvent(tweet);
});
```